# Наилучший способ сортировки массива.

Tags: массивы, сортировка, алгоритм

Какой способ является самым лучшим и по вашему мнению и почему? Есть ли способы быстрее способа, основанного на алгоритме "быстрой сортировки"? Если да, то будьте добры рассказать, где можно о нем почитать.

Comment: Лучшего метода (для всех случаев) не бывает. Если имеются какие-либо предположение относительно структуры входных данных, то можно оптимизировать процесс сортировки. Хорошая вводная статья есть на http://clck.ru/EiGA

Answer (score 16):

- *Лучшего способа нет*, если говорить о "разумных" алгоритмах и не учитывать эзотерику типа [**Bogosort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) или [**Intelligent Design Sort.**](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/intelligentdesignsort.html)

> - Стандартные операции `sort` в современных языках обычно используют разные алгоритмы в зависимости от размера входных данных. То есть, на маленьких размерах массивов `O(N^2)` сортировка вставками часто оказывается более эффективной, чем, например, `O(N log N)` быстрая сортировка.
> - Естественно, что для больших размеров выбирается сортировка с `O(N log N)` временем работы.

- Можно строго доказать, что, если `S` - алгоритм сортировки, основанный на построении дерева решений, то `O(N log N)` - это минимальное возможное время работы алгоритма `S` в худшем его случае. А это означает, что все алгоритмы типа `quicksort`, `mergesort`, сортировки вставками и т.п. не могут работать за время, меньшее, чем `O(N log N)`.

> Тем не менее, есть сортировки, которые не используют деревья решений и работают **за линейное время** при некоторых ограничениях. Например, [**поразрядная сортировка.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)

- Из литературы - [**Cormen, Introduction To Algorithms.**](http://books.google.ru/books/about/Introduction_To_Algorithms.html?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&redir_esc=y)

Comment: Кроме временной сложности желательно не забывать и требования к вспомогательной памяти. А из литературы можно вспомнить ещё третий том "Искусства программирования" Д. Кнута. Ну и ряд других книг...

Comment: Да, спасибо вам. Поразрядная сортировка удивила меня, ведь это уже эзотерика.

Comment: Надо только помнить, что за O(nlogn) стоит константа, поэтому на практике можно сортировать быстрей, чем quicksort. Для этого есть гибридные сортировки вроде Introsort или Timsort. Еще бывает не всегда важна именно верхняя крышка, иногда ориентируются на средний случай.

Answer (score 14):

я просто оставлю это здесь

[image]

источник: [Алгоритм сортировки Timsort](http://habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/133303/)

Answer (score 7):

Коротко.

[@Котик_хочет_кушать](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) правильно сказал, что *лучшего способа нет*.

Из почти всегда применимых алгоритмов **quicksort** IMHO самый быстрый (время O(N*log N)), хотя (даже правильно реализованый) изредка (на практике **очень редко**) может привести к времени порядка O(N^2).
Он требует log N дополнительной памяти, т.е. на практике можете считать, что не требует.
Основной недостаток **quicksort** - это **неустойчивый** (unstable) алгоритм.

Сортировка называется **устойчивой**, если порядок записей с **одинаковыми** ключами после сортировки сохраняется. Очевидно, что если Вы сортируете массив чисел, то устойчивость алгоритма неважна (одно число 10 от другого 10 неотличимо). Для сортровки записей (структур) это не так (хотя зависит от прикладной задачи).

Из устойчивых сортировок (я рассматриваю алгоритмы со временем O(N*log N)) IMHO самым быстрым является сортировка слиянием (**mergesort**) в ее почти простейшей реализации, требующий N/2 дополнительной памяти.

Похожие результаты (иногда м.б. даже быстрее, но обычно медленнее) показывает **timsort** (это тоже разновидность сортировки слиянием). Обычно она требует 30-40% N дополнительной памяти.

Также (пользуясь случаем) хочу обратить внимание на [**yamsort**](http://code.google.com/p/yamsort/). Еще один алгоритм и программа устойчивой (stable) сортировки слиянием c небольшой (около 6 % от размера сортируемого массива) дополнительной памятью. Он несколько медленнее timsort, но при сортировке очень больших массивов (особенно в многопользовательских системах), когда дополниетельная память вызывает paging, это алгоритм оказывается значительно быстрее других устойчивых сортировок.

По [этой ссылке](http://code.google.com/p/yamsort/source/browse/#svn) (в Sourse/Readme.txt) описан данный алгоритм и есть некоторые результаты измерения разных сортировок, а также исходники нескольких сортировок и пример программы для их измерения.

Comment: Спасибо.

---
Из ваших рассуждений и утверждений возник подвопрос. Существует ли алгоритм сортировки с линейным временем выполнения сортировки?

Comment: Если ограниченного круга задач посмотрите на [сортировку подсчетом](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC).

Видимо этот метод можно модифицировать (особенно привлекательно для связных списков) строя списки указателей на записи для каждого ключа.

Вопрос вообще-то интересный. Если есть время, попробуйте поиграйтесь, развейте идею.

Comment: По-моему выше написан источник Кормен, Лайзерсон и ко, там все сортировки за линейное время описаны. И также там доказано, что меньше чем за nlogn при условии, что надо сравнивать, нельзя отсортировать